# cumsum and product based on Unique ID

Tags: r, cumsum

Am working on a large dataset to calculate a single value in R. I believe the CUMSUM and cum product would work. But I don't know-how

```
county_id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
res <- c(2,3,2,4,2,4,3,3,2)
```

I need a function that can simply give me a single value as follows
for every county_id, then I need the total.
Example, for county_id=1 the total for res is calculated manually as

```
2(3+2+4)+3(2+4)+2(4)
```

for county_id=2 the total for res is calculated manually as

```
2(4+3)+4(3)
```

for county_id=3 the total for res is calculated manually as

```
3(2)
```

Then it sums all this into a single variable

```
44+26+6=76
```

NB my county_id run from 1:47 and each county_id could have up to 200 res

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using `tidyverse` functions.

For each `county_id` we multiply the current `res` value with the `sum` of `res` value after it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 <- df %>%
         group_by(county_id) %>%
         summarise(result = sum(map_dbl(row_number(), 
                           ~res[.x] * sum(res[(.x + 1):n()])), na.rm = TRUE))

df1
#  county_id result
#      <dbl>  <dbl>
#1         1     44
#2         2     26
#3         3      6
```

To get total `sum` you can then do :

```
sum(df1$result)
#[1] 76
```

**data**

```
county_id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
res <- c(2,3,2,4,2,4,3,3,2)
df <- data.frame(county_id, res)
```

Comment: Thankyou soo much. suppose I want to create a 44 by 44 matrix using the single generated value with 1 in the diagonals and the single value in all the other cells, could you please kindly help?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, perhaps it is better to ask as a new question.

Comment: hello Ronak, i posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020355/creating-n-by-n-matrix-with-1-in-main-diagonal-and-common-value-say-0-012-in-the

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate` with `cumsum` like:

```
x <- aggregate(res, list(county_id)
 , function(x) sum(rev(cumsum(rev(x[-1])))*x[-length(x)]))
#Group.1  x
#1       1 44
#2       2 26
#3       3  6
sum(x[,2])
#[1] 76
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sum the product of the pairwise combinations:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(county_id) %>%
  summarise(x = sum(combn(res, 2, FUN = prod)))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  county_id     x
      <dbl> <dbl>
1         1    44
2         2    26
3         3     6
```

Base R:

```
aggregate(res ~ county_id, dat, FUN = function(x) sum(combn(x, 2, FUN = prod)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Another option is to use SPSS syntax

// You need to count the number of variables with valid responses
count x1=var1 to var4(1 thr hi).
execute.

// 1st thing is to declare a variable that will hold your cumulative sum
// Declare your variables in terms of a vector
//You then loop twice. The 1st loop being from the 1st variable to the number of 
//variables with data (x1). The 2nd loop will be from the 1st variable to the    `
//variable in (1st loop-1) for all variables with data.`
//Lastly you need to get a cumulative sum based on your formulae
// This syntax can be replicated in other software.

compute index1=0.
vector x=var1 to var4.
loop #i=1 to x1.
loop #j=1 to #i-1 if not missing(x(#i)).
compute index1=index1+(x(#j)*sum(x(#i))).
end loop.
end loop.
execute.
```

Comment: Thanks, P Ngugi. This is great especially for SPSS users