# creating n by n matrix with 1 in main diagonal and common value say 0.012 in the other cells using R software

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create an n by n matrix that looks like this
if `n=4 and my alpha=0.01` then my matrix
[image] using R software

I would appreciate if i can get something using this working to reproduce the matrix above

```
     n=5
    i=0
    alpha=0.01
    R=matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n)
    while(i<n){
      R[i+1,]=alpha
      i=i+1}
    R
```

but with the above code, all my diagonals are 0.01. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a matrix of 0.01's and set the diagonal to 1:

```
 n <- 5
 alpha <- 0.01
 diagonal_val <- 1
 m <- matrix(alpha, n, n)
 diag(m) <- diagonal_val
```

**Update**
The OP requested to elaborate on the brute-force approach to create matrices:

```
n <- 5
alpha <- 0.01
R <- matrix(NA, n,n)
for (i in 1:n){
  for (j in 1:n){
    if (i==j){
      R[i,j] <- 1.
    } else {
      R[i,j] <- alpha
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1.00 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01
[2,] 0.01 1.00 0.01 0.01 0.01
[3,] 0.01 0.01 1.00 0.01 0.01
[4,] 0.01 0.01 0.01 1.00 0.01
[5,] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 1.00
```

Comment: dear slava, i have edited the question to include more details. Kindly what am i doing wrong?